# Bash + gnuplot script for many files in folder

Tags: bash, gnuplot

Here is a problem I am facing since few days. I want to shortcut a lot of work by doing simple script.. but script is not working properly.

The script should do:

1. Tail 3 lines of files in specified directories ${FOLDER}
2. Change extenstion from .gplt to none.
3. Use gnuplot function to plot an output.

All files in those folders begins with :

```
set term postscript color
set output "x_101.ps"
plot "-" title "magU" with lines
0   0
5.00501e-06     0.00301606
1.001e-05   0.00603211
...
```

So I am stuck with this, and some parts are not working and thats why I am asking you guys if someone could look on this:

```
#!/bin/bash

rename(){
newname = $(basename .gplt)
}

FOLDER=(
~/Dokumenty/mgr/obliczenia_OF/ReConst/H20_ReConst_v1/postProcessing/sets/*
~/Dokumenty/mgr/obliczenia_OF/ReConst/H20_ReConst_v2/postProcessing/sets/*
~/Dokumenty/mgr/obliczenia_OF/ReConst/H20_ReConst_v3/postProcessing/sets/*
~/Dokumenty/mgr/obliczenia_OF/ReConst/H20_ReConst_v4/postProcessing/sets/*

~/Dokumenty/mgr/obliczenia_OF/ReConst/R134_ReConst_v1/postProcessing/sets/*
~/Dokumenty/mgr/obliczenia_OF/ReConst/R134_ReConst_v2/postProcessing/sets/*
~/Dokumenty/mgr/obliczenia_OF/ReConst/R134_ReConst_v3/postProcessing/sets/*
~/Dokumenty/mgr/obliczenia_OF/ReConst/R134_ReConst_v4/postProcessing/sets/*


~/Dokumenty/mgr/obliczenia_OF/ReConst/OM_ReConst_v1/postProcessing/sets/*
~/Dokumenty/mgr/obliczenia_OF/ReConst/OM_ReConst_v2/postProcessing/sets/*
~/Dokumenty/mgr/obliczenia_OF/ReConst/OM_ReConst_v3/postProcessing/sets/*
~/Dokumenty/mgr/obliczenia_OF/ReConst/OM_ReConst_v4/postProcessing/sets/*

~/Dokumenty/mgr/obliczenia_OF/PeConst/R134_PecletConst_v1/postProcessing/sets/*
~/Dokumenty/mgr/obliczenia_OF/PeConst/R134_PecletConst_v2/postProcessing/sets/*
~/Dokumenty/mgr/obliczenia_OF/PeConst/R134_PecletConst_v3/postProcessing/sets/*
~/Dokumenty/mgr/obliczenia_OF/PeConst/R134_PecletConst_v4/postProcessing/sets/*

~/Dokumenty/mgr/obliczenia_OF/PeConst/OM_PecletConst_v1/postProcessing/sets/*
~/Dokumenty/mgr/obliczenia_OF/PeConst/OM_PecletConst_v2/postProcessing/sets/*
~/Dokumenty/mgr/obliczenia_OF/PeConst/OM_PecletConst_v3/postProcessing/sets/*
~/Dokumenty/mgr/obliczenia_OF/PeConst/OM_PecletConst_v4/postProcessing/sets/*
)

for file in *; do
    tail -n+3 ${file} >> ${file}
done

for ff in *; do
rename ${ff}
done

for f in *; do
gnuplot <<- EOF
set terminal png size 400,250
set output '${f}.png'
set grid
set xlabel 'y' rotate by 360
set ylabel 'U(y)'
plot "${f}" using 2:1 with lines
EOF
done
```

PS. There is one more thing. The FOLDERS have sub-folder that why I used this:

```
sets/*
```

at the end and I am worried it might be wrong.

Cheers
jilsu.

Comment: `tail -n+3` gives all lines from (including) line number 3.. is this correct?

Comment: So what you want to do is to change all `.gplt` files such that they produce a `.png` instead of a postscript file? But you want to keep the original `.gplt` files?

Answer (score 2):

You aren't using `FOLDER` anywhere. You keep using `*` in your loops instead. You want to use `"${FOLDER[@]}"` in your loops.

Your `rename` function is syntactically invalid. Shell assignment lines require no spaces around the `=`. So it would need to be `newname=$(basename .gplt)` but that is just assigning a variable and not actually renaming any files.

You also likely don't need that `rename` function if all you want is to change `file.gplt` to `file.png` in the output `gnuplot` call. You can, instead, just use `$(basename "$f" .gplt)` in the `HEREDOC`.

Answer (score 1):

there seem to be a couple of problems:

The approach with * at the end will not work, use find instead.

```
find ${FOLDER[i]} -type f
```

i am not sure what you want to achieve with that one:

```
 tail -n+3 ${file} >> ${file}
```

what it DOES is duplicating the content of $file starting from line 3 (you are appending to the file you read from).